# Making sure expected methods are callable

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel

So I was testing a class and expecting it to call a method from a dependency:

```
$userMock = Mockery::mock('User');
$userMock->shouldReceive('updateTimestamps')->once()->andReturn($userMock);
```

Sure the test passed, but the problem was I didn't realize `updateTimestamps` was a private method! So even if the test passed it will fail if I try it manually. Is there a way to make sure that all methods that I give expectations are callable?

Answer (score 0):

The [PHP Reflection Class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) will allow you to test this.